# Ignore a particular folder in htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am facing issues regarding my `.htaccess`. The `.htaccess` works, but it causes a problem with the admin folder. Would it be possible to exclude that specific folder from this `.htaccess`? Here is my `.htaccess`. It is outside the admin folder.

```
Options -MultiViews

ErrorDocument 404 http://localhost/blo-prt/err.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L,QSA]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^blo/([^/\.]+)?$ blo-det.php?postlist=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^category/blo/([^/\.]+)?$ blo-prior.php?bloglist=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^tep/([^/\.]+)?$ temp-det.php?telist=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^category/tep/([^/\.]+)?$ temp-of-prior.php?tlist=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: For clarification, is that .htaccess in the parent directory of the admin folder?

Comment: no .htaccess is out of the admin folder

Comment: What folder is the .htaccess in, and what folder is the admin folder in?

Comment: it all started to affect when i added the codes for removing the .php extension when i removed it works fine

Comment: Is the .htaccess in the same folder where the admin folder is?

Comment: Okay the .htaccess is in `http://localhost/blo-prt/` i mean in blo-prt folder and the admin structure is like this `http://localhost/blo-prt/admin` i mean `blo-prt/admin` where i have no .htaccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add this to your RewriteConds:

```
# if request is not for the /admin/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin/ [NC]
```

Personally, I use this code to remove the .php extension:

```
# enable url rewriting
RewriteEngine On 

# remove .php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [NC,L]
```

Also, you should only type RewriteEngineOn just once at the top of the file.

Comment: thanks for helping codes are 100% working but my admin folder codes are affected they are still disturbed

Comment: Also, is your admin folder name "admin"

Comment: yes its admin i saw that when i am using that codes of yours or of mine to remove the .php extension the error arises

Comment: Maybe the error is in your code. Try if it works when you remove the whole .htaccess file

Comment: yes when i remove the whole .htaccess then all codes of mine are working fine but i need them

Comment: You have 6 different parts in your .htaccess, try removing all but one of them and see which part causes the problem

Comment: that i mentioned earlier that .php extension code is my foe right now

Comment: Which part is that?

Comment: that .php extension codes written down in .htaccess

Comment: hey my codes are working fine even in admin folder one  but .php is removed from self i have not used the codes to remove the .php. Do this can happen???

Comment: Thanks!!! it worked for me  just i have made a small change into it  i put this code just after the RewriteEngine On `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(admin) [NC]`